# Custom header with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

Tags: vba, excel, serverxmlhttp

I am currently trying to use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to send a POST http request.
I need to add a custom header "Auth" so that my requests get authorized but it doesn't seem to work. 
Here is the code for my post function:

```
Function post(path As String, authToken As String, postData As String) As String
  Dim xhr As Object
  Dim message As String
On Error GoTo error:

  Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  xhr.Open "POST", path, False
  xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  xhr.setRequestHeader "Auth", authToken
  xhr.send postData

  If xhr.Status = 200 Then
    message = xhr.responseText
  Else
    message = xhr.Status & ": " & xhr.statusText
  End If

  Set xhr = Nothing
  post = message
error:
  Debug.Print "Error " & Err.Number; ":" & Err.Description
End Function
```

And I end up with "Error -2147012746 Requested Header was not found" (The message is actually translated since I use a different language on my computer).

However I didn't have this problem with the "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" Object. 
Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sure your header is named "Auth", not "Authorization"? Try `xhr.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", authToken`

Comment: Yes it is named "Auth" and sadly it is not possible to change it at this point (it was not created by me and it is already used by multiple clients) :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the call to SetRequestHeader to use a string literal. I duplicated the problem when `authToken` does not have a value set.

Change from this

```
xhr.setRequestHeader "Auth", authToken
```

To this

```
xhr.setRequestHeader "Auth", "testdatahere"
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually works with the variable if *authToken* isn't an empty string. I don't really like to send random auth value but as long as it works... Thanks again, have a great day !