# Batch download file from URL How to add HTTP Headers?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cookies, cmd

I am currently using a bat file to download a JSON page

But I get an error because I need to add headers:

{"errorcode":"9999"}

I should mainly add only a cookie for the request

How can i add the cookie header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom header with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028710/custom-header-with-msxml2-serverxmlhttp)

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316209/download-files-via-batch-with-custom-header/47316807#47316807

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995919/curl-how-to-send-cookies-via-command-line#15996114).

Comment: But I do not know how to integrate this into the code: curl -c /path/to/cookiefile http://yourhost/